# Center equations in lyx thesis template

Tags: lyx

I'm using the Lyx thesis template. My equations are aligned to the left, and I would like to have them centered instead. Hoowever when I go to Document settings->Math options I only have the options of default which align the equations to the left, or the option of indenting the equation, which is not really what I want, since then all the indentation space is not used.
How can I change this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe try the `ceqn` environment, from `nccmath`.

Comment: Thanks! How would I change that in Lyx, so that is the standard used in all my equations?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the code of the template. I would say that probably there's somewhere the  option `fleqn`. In this case the simplest would be to remove it.